# Exchange EWS: class "DistinguishedFolderIdType" not defined

Tags: exchangewebservices

I'm using Exchange web services, trying to create a calendar entry in another user's mailbox. My account in EWS has rights to do this, and I can successfully use Impersonation to create thes appointment in any mailbox.

However, some examples I've seen of doing this, use an instance of `DistinguishedFolderIdType`, not impersonation, to set the mailbox for the appointment.

Problem is, this class simply isn't appearing in my installation of the EWS SDK for Visual Studio. It's v1.1, [obtained here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13480), but can't be found in Object Explorer. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `DistinguishedFolderIdType` is not part of the EWS Managed API.

If you do not use the EWS Managed API but generate your own SOAP client proxy manually from Visual Studio by adding a reference to the EWS .asmx service, the generated proxy will contain `DistinguishedFolderIdType`.

However, depending on what you are trying to accomplish, you should be able to do it using the classes provided på EWS Managed API 1.1 and you won't need `DistinguishedFolderIdType`.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you. All I need to do is add appointments to calendars in several different mailboxes. I currently use impersonation to do this, but wondered (after seeing the above method) if that was the "best" way to do it?

Comment: @ingredient_15939: Impersonation is one way to do it. If you have the right permissions you may also bind to another user's calendar by using delegate access: var folder = Folder.Bind(service, new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new Mailbox("somebody@domain.com")));